# if entry from database is of a certain value, substitute an image on the report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to read a value from my database, and depending on the character, have a different image show. Basically the values will either be b,r,g,or y for blue, red, green yellow and in the report I would like to show a colored circle corresponding to the entry. Does anyone know a quick way to do this? I am new to crystal reports. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Circles are created using a rectangle (yes, really).  Set the roundness=100%.  Unfortunately, you can't hide/show (suppress, In Crystal's vernacular) a rectangle with conditional logic.  Nor can you change its x and y values.  So, for your purposes, its useless.

One option is to insert four, colored, images of circles.  Suppress all but the one that you want to display.

Another option is to insert a text box, then add a circular, wingding character to it (Word can help w/ this).  Use the text box's conditional formatting to change its color.

Comment: Although you cannot suppress rectangles you can sometimes suppress the section they are in and use "underlay following section" together to achieve desired result

Answer (score 0):

One additional suggestion to craig. You could:

- create an image file for each of the coloured circles
- add one of these coloured circles to the report
- right click, format graphic
- from the picture tab, select the formula editor for graphic location
- enter a formula which looks for the relevant coloured circle image file

  'C:\circles\' + {table.field} + '.jpg'

L

Comment: The path might be a bit fragile, especially if you plan to deploy it to a BOE environment.  I like the creativity, however.

Comment: Could even store the images in the database then do a simple join :)

Comment: I considered that as well.  I'd probably encapsulate that in a subreport, however.

Comment: I eventually plan to include this report with an asp.net project I am working on, would this work if linked to the image folder in my project then linked? I wouldn't want to create any errors when moving this to the web.